# How to rewrite rules for WP-security in Nginx?

Tags: security, nginx

I have a WordPress website on a VPS running nginx. I have installed the WP Security plugin to improve the security of my site. After changing all the settings to my liking, a pop-up notifies me that I need rewrite the rules to save my changes. Part of it said "See the Better WP Security Dashboard for a list of the rewrite rules you will need." The list of rewrite rules can be found here:

```
# BEGIN Better WP Security
    # Begin HackRepair.com Blacklist
        if ($http_user_agent ~* "^BlackWidow"){ return 403; }
        if ($http_user_agent ~ "^Bolt"){ return 403; }
        if ($http_user_agent ~* "CazoodleBot"){ return 403; }
        if ($http_user_agent ~* "^ChinaClaw"){ return 403; }
        if ($http_user_agent ~* "^Custo"){ return 403; }
        if ($http_user_agent ~ "^Default"){ return 403; }
        if ($http_user_agent ~* "^DIIbot"){ return 403; }
        if ($http_user_agent ~* "^DISCo"){ return 403; }
        if ($http_user_agent ~* "discobot"){ return 403; }
        if ($http_user_agent ~* "^eCatch"){ return 403; }
        if ($http_user_agent ~* "ecxi"){ return 403; }
        if ($http_user_agent ~* "^EirGrabber"){ return 403; }
        if ($http_user_agent ~* "^EmailCollector"){ return 403; }
        if ($http_user_agent ~* "^EmailSiphon"){ return 403; }
        if ($http_user_agent ~* "^EmailWolf"){ return 403; }
        if ($http_user_agent ~* "^ExtractorPro"){ return 403; }
        if ($http_user_agent ~* "^EyeNetIE"){ return 403; }
        if ($http_user_agent ~* "^FlashGet"){ return 403; }
        if ($http_user_agent ~* "^GetRight"){ return 403; }
        if ($http_user_agent ~* "^GetWeb!"){ return 403; }
        if ($http_user_agent ~* "^Go!Zilla"){ return 403; }
        if ($http_user_agent ~* "^Go-Ahead-Got-It"){ return 403; }
        if ($http_user_agent ~* "^GrabNet"){ return 403; }
        if ($http_user_agent ~* "^Grafula"){ return 403; }
        if ($http_user_agent ~* "GT::WWW"){ return 403; }
        if ($http_user_agent ~* "heritrix"){ return 403; }
        if ($http_user_agent ~* "^HMView"){ return 403; }
        if ($http_user_agent ~* "HTTP::Lite"){ return 403; }
        if ($http_user_agent ~* "HTTrack"){ return 403; }
        if ($http_user_agent ~* "ia_archiver"){ return 403; }
        if ($http_user_agent ~* "IDBot"){ return 403; }
        if ($http_user_agent ~* "id-search"){ return 403; }
        if ($http_user_agent ~* "id-search.org"){ return 403; }
        if ($http_user_agent ~* "^InterGET"){ return 403; }
        if ($http_user_agent ~* "^InternetSeer.com"){ return 403; }
        if ($http_user_agent ~* "IRLbot"){ return 403; }
        if ($http_user_agent ~* "^Java"){ return 403; }
        if ($http_user_agent ~* "^JetCar"){ return 403; }
        if ($http_user_agent ~* "^larbin"){ return 403; }
        if ($http_user_agent ~* "^LeechFTP"){ return 403; }
        if ($http_user_agent ~* "libwww"){ return 403; }
        if ($http_user_agent ~* "libwww-perl"){ return 403; }
        if ($http_user_agent ~* "^Link"){ return 403; }
        if ($http_user_agent ~* "LinksManager.com_bot"){ return 403; }
        if ($http_user_agent ~* "linkwalker"){ return 403; }
        if ($http_user_agent ~* "lwp-trivial"){ return 403; }
        if ($http_user_agent ~* "^Maxthon$"){ return 403; }
        if ($http_user_agent ~* "MFC_Tear_Sample"){ return 403; }
        if ($http_user_agent ~* "^microsoft.url"){ return 403; }
        if ($http_user_agent ~ "Microsoft"){ return 403; }
        if ($http_user_agent ~* "^Mozilla.*Indy"){ return 403; }
        if ($http_user_agent ~* "^Mozilla.*NEWT"){ return 403; }
        if ($http_user_agent ~* "^MSFrontPage"){ return 403; }
        if ($http_user_agent ~* "^Navroad"){ return 403; }
        if ($http_user_agent ~* "^NearSite"){ return 403; }
        if ($http_user_agent ~* "^NetAnts"){ return 403; }
        if ($http_user_agent ~* "^NetSpider"){ return 403; }
        if ($http_user_agent ~* "^NetZIP"){ return 403; }
        if ($http_user_agent ~* "^Nutch"){ return 403; }
        if ($http_user_agent ~* "^Octopus"){ return 403; }
        if ($http_user_agent ~* "^PageGrabber"){ return 403; }
        if ($http_user_agent ~* "panscient.com"){ return 403; }
        if ($http_user_agent ~* "^pavuk"){ return 403; }
        if ($http_user_agent ~* "PECL::HTTP"){ return 403; }
        if ($http_user_agent ~* "^PeoplePal"){ return 403; }
        if ($http_user_agent ~* "^pcBrowser"){ return 403; }
        if ($http_user_agent ~* "PHPCrawl"){ return 403; }
        if ($http_user_agent ~* "PleaseCrawl"){ return 403; }
        if ($http_user_agent ~* "^psbot"){ return 403; }
        if ($http_user_agent ~* "^RealDownload"){ return 403; }
        if ($http_user_agent ~* "^ReGet"){ return 403; }
        if ($http_user_agent ~ "^Rippers"){ return 403; }
        if ($http_user_agent ~* "SBIder"){ return 403; }
        if ($http_user_agent ~* "^SeaMonkey$"){ return 403; }
        if ($http_user_agent ~* "^sitecheck.internetseer.com"){ return 403; }
        if ($http_user_agent ~* "^SiteSnagger"){ return 403; }
        if ($http_user_agent ~* "^SmartDownload"){ return 403; }
        if ($http_user_agent ~* "Snoopy"){ return 403; }
        if ($http_user_agent ~* "Steeler"){ return 403; }
        if ($http_user_agent ~* "^SuperBot"){ return 403; }
        if ($http_user_agent ~* "^SuperHTTP"){ return 403; }
        if ($http_user_agent ~* "^Surfbot"){ return 403; }
        if ($http_user_agent ~* "^tAkeOut"){ return 403; }
        if ($http_user_agent ~ "^Teleport"){ return 403; }
        if ($http_user_agent ~ "^Toata"){ return 403; }
        if ($http_user_agent ~* "URI::Fetch"){ return 403; }
        if ($http_user_agent ~* "urllib"){ return 403; }
        if ($http_user_agent ~* "User-Agent"){ return 403; }
        if ($http_user_agent ~* "^VoidEYE"){ return 403; }
        if ($http_user_agent ~* "webalta"){ return 403; }
        if ($http_user_agent ~* "^WebAuto"){ return 403; }
        if ($http_user_agent ~* "^[Ww]eb[Bb]andit"){ return 403; }
        if ($http_user_agent ~* "WebCollage"){ return 403; }
        if ($http_user_agent ~* "^WebCopier"){ return 403; }
        if ($http_user_agent ~* "^WebFetch"){ return 403; }
        if ($http_user_agent ~* "^WebLeacher"){ return 403; }
        if ($http_user_agent ~* "^WebReaper"){ return 403; }
        if ($http_user_agent ~* "^WebSauger"){ return 403; }
        if ($http_user_agent ~* "^WebStripper"){ return 403; }
        if ($http_user_agent ~* "^WebWhacker"){ return 403; }
        if ($http_user_agent ~* "^WebZIP"){ return 403; }
        if ($http_user_agent ~* "^Wget"){ return 403; }
        if ($http_user_agent ~* "^Widow"){ return 403; }
        if ($http_user_agent ~* "^WWW-Mechanize"){ return 403; }
        if ($http_user_agent ~* "^WWWOFFLE"){ return 403; }
        if ($http_user_agent ~* "zermelo"){ return 403; }
        if ($http_user_agent ~* "^Zeus"){ return 403; }
        if ($http_user_agent ~* "^Zeus.*Webster"){ return 403; }
        if ($http_user_agent ~* "ZyBorg"){ return 403; }
    # End HackRepair.com Blacklist

    location ~ /\.ht { deny all; }
    location ~ wp-config.php { deny all; }
    location ~ readme.html { deny all; }
    location ~ readme.txt { deny all; }
    location ~ /install.php { deny all; }
    set $susquery 0;
    set $rule_2 0;
    set $rule_3 0;
    rewrite ^wp-includes/(.*).php /not_found last;
    rewrite ^/wp-admin/includes(.*)$ /not_found last;
    if ($request_method ~* "^(TRACE|DELETE|TRACK)"){ return 403; }
    if ($args ~* "\.\./") { set $susquery 1; }
    if ($args ~* ".(bash|git|hg|log|svn|swp|cvs)") { set $susquery 1; }
    if ($args ~* "etc/passwd") { set $susquery 1; }
    if ($args ~* "boot.ini") { set $susquery 1; }
    if ($args ~* "ftp:") { set $susquery 1; }
    if ($args ~* "http:") { set $susquery 1; }
    if ($args ~* "https:") { set $susquery 1; }
    if ($args ~* "(<|%3C).*script.*(>|%3E)") { set $susquery 1; }
    if ($args ~* "mosConfig_[a-zA-Z_]{1,21}(=|%3D)") { set $susquery 1; }
    if ($args ~* "base64_encode") { set $susquery 1; }
    if ($args ~* "(%24&x)") { set $susquery 1; }
    if ($args ~* "(\[|\]|\(|\)|<|>|ê|\"|;|\?|\*|=$)"){ set $susquery 1; }
    if ($args ~* "(&#x22;|&#x27;|&#x3C;|&#x3E;|&#x5C;|&#x7B;|&#x7C;|%24&x)"){ set $susquery 1; }
    if ($args ~* "(127.0)") { set $susquery 1; }
    if ($args ~* "(%0|%A|%B|%C|%D|%E|%F)") { set $susquery 1; }
    if ($args ~* "(globals|encode|localhost|loopback)") { set $susquery 1; }
    if ($args ~* "(request|select|insert|concat|union|declare)") { set $susquery 1; }
    if ($http_cookie !~* "wordpress_logged_in_" ) {
        set $susquery 2$susquery;
        set $rule_2 1;
        set $rule_3 1;
    }
    if ($args !~ "^loggedout=true") { set $susquery 3$susquery; }
    if ($susquery = 4321) { return 403; }
    rewrite ^/login/?$ /wp-login.php?nw61e1jrijsnetr1xokgx redirect;
    if ($rule_2 = 1) { rewrite ^/totalaccess/?$ /wp-login.php?nw61e1jrijsnetr1xokgx&redirect_to=/wp-admin/ redirect; }
    if ($rule_2 = 0) { rewrite ^/totalaccess/?$ /wp-admin/?nw61e1jrijsnetr1xokgx redirect; }
    rewrite ^/register/?$ /wp-login.php?nw61e1jrijsnetr1xokgx&action=register redirect;
    if ($uri !~ "^(.*)admin-ajax.php") { set $rule_3 2$rule_3; }
    if ($http_referer !~* wp-admin ) { set $rule_3 3$rule_3; }
    if ($http_referer !~* wp-login.php ) { set $rule_3 4$rule_3; }
    if ($http_referer !~* login ) { set $rule_3 5$rule_3; }
    if ($http_referer !~* totalaccess ) { set $rule_3 6$rule_3; }
    if ($http_referer !~* register ) { set $rule_3 7$rule_3; }
    if ($args !~ "^action=logout") { set $rule_3 8$rule_3; }
    if ($args !~ "^nw61e1jrijsnetr1xokgx") { set $rule_3 9$rule_3; }
    if ($args !~ "^action=rp") { set $rule_3 0$rule_3; }
    if ($args !~ "^action=register") { set $rule_3 a$rule_3; }
    if ($args !~ "^action=postpass") { set $rule_3 b$rule_3; }
    if ($rule_3 = ba0987654321) {
        rewrite ^(.*/)?wp-login.php /not_found redirect;
        rewrite ^/wp-admin(.*)$ /not_found redirect;
    }
# END Better WP Security
```

I'm not actually sure whether the changes from the plugin have really taken effect since I have modified any file myself with these rules. I asked and did some Googling, but I could not find an answer. So I'm just wondering how I can "rewrite" this rules to make sure the security is properly in place.

Comment: You can for example try to view the `readme.html` file in your browser.

Comment: Hello. I did take a look at the readme files, but unfortunately they did not seem to answer this question.

Comment: then it looks like you aren't including it correctly, if it's included then you should get a `403 Forbidden` message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Please try this:**

**1)** Save the rewrite rules to the file: `/absolute/path/to/wp_security.conf`.

**2)** Then include it in your NginX configuration file, with the line:

```
           include /absolute/path/to/wp_security.conf;
```

and place it in the *server* context:

```
server {
           #... cut ...       

           ##
           # include the Better WP Security configuration file
           ##
           include /absolute/path/to/wp_security.conf;

           location / {
                        try_files  $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
           }

           #... cut ...           
}
```

**3)** Remember to reload NginX:

```
nginx -t && service nginx reload
```

**4)** One of the things you can easily test is this part:

```
location ~ readme.html { deny all; }
```

When this rule is activated it should deny access to the `readme.html` file when you try to view it in a browser:

[image: 403]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However, I get this error: root@MainServer:/etc/nginx# nginx -t && service nginx reload
nginx: [emerg] "if" directive is not allowed here in /var/www/wp-content/plugins/better-wp-  security/rules.conf:3
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
root@MainServer:/etc/nginx# service nginx status
 * nginx is running

My full file can be found here: http://pastebin.com/iMgAXDkZ

Comment: You have added it in the `http` context, not the `server` context. Take a look into the `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*` files.

Comment: Ah, I'm pretty sure that did it. Thanks for helping a novice like me!

Answer (score 0):

I believe I came across this article not too long ago and tested your rewrite rules.  One rule I have to warn you about. The line

```
 if ($http_user_agent ~* "^**Custo**"){ return 403; }
```

ends up disabling the customize.php file in WordPress.  If the user tries to customize the theme in the dashboard (which personally any customizations done within WP is a bit dangerous), it will appear broken or missing css.